# UPDATE from SELECT: Join Method

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using this

```sql
UPDATE stockout_details
SET 
stockout_details.chaloutinv=stockin_details.inv_cha
FROM stockout_details 
INNER JOIN stockin_details
ON stockin_details.marka = stockout_details.marka and stockin_details.purchi = stockout_details.purchi and 
stockin_details.chalan = stockout_details.chalan and stockin_details.room = stockout_details.room and
stockin_details.rack = stockout_details.rack
```

and the error is

```sql
UPDATE stockout_details
SET 
stockout_details.chaloutinv=stockin_details.inv_cha
FROM stockout_details 
INNER JOIN
'stockin_details'
ON stockin_details.marka = stockout_details.marka and stockin_details.purchi = stockout_details.purchi and 
stockin_details.chalan = stockout_details.chalan and stockin_details.room = stockout_details.room and
stockin_details.rack = stockout_details.rack;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM stockout_details
> INNER JOIN
> 'stockin_details'
> ON stockin_details.mar...' at line 4

Comment: The point is, you should be formatting your posts, Muhummad . [so] supports markdown, and you should be making efforts to make your question readable for other users.

Comment: You have your table in a *'string literal'*. Probably shouldn't do that.

Comment: `UPDATE ... SET .. FROM` is not valid syntax. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE with JOIN should looks like:

```
UPDATE T1,T2
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.C1 = T2.C1
SET T1.C2 = T2.C2,
      T2.C3 = expr
WHERE condition
```

So you don't need to add `FROM table`

Comment: when i add this UPDATE stockout_details,stockin_details 
INNER JOIN stockin_details ON 
stockin_details.marka = stockout_details.marka and stockin_details.purchi = stockout_details.purchi and 
stockin_details.chalan = stockout_details.chalan and stockin_details.room = stockout_details.room and
stockin_details.rack = stockout_details.rack 
SET 
stockout_details.chaloutinv=stockin_details.inv_cha

Comment: the error is Not unique table/alias: 'stockin_details'

Comment: Yes, this also an error) use backticks (` symbol) with names of table/column

Comment: dear  its not properly work can you write it?

Comment: Try this ``UPDATE `stockout_details`
SET 
`stockout_details`.`chaloutinv`=`stockin_details`.`inv_cha`
INNER JOIN `stockin_details`
ON `stockin_details`.`marka` = `stockout_details`.`marka` AND `stockin_details`.`purchi` = `stockout_details`.`purchi` AND
`stockin_details`.`chalan` = `stockout_details`.`chalan` AND `stockin_details`.`room` = `stockout_details`.`room` AND
`stockin_details`.`rack` = `stockout_details`.`rack` ``

Comment: there is the error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN `stockin_details` ON `stockin_details`.`marka` = `stockout_details...' at line 1

Comment: Sorry, forget that. You should put JOIN before SET, like this: ``UPDATE `stockout_details` INNER JOIN `stockin_details` ON `stockin_details`.`marka` = `stockout_details`.`marka` AND `stockin_details`.`purchi` = `stockout_details`.`purchi` AND `stockin_details`.`chalan` = `stockout_details`.`chalan` AND `stockin_details`.`room` = `stockout_details`.`room` AND `stockin_details`.`rack` = `stockout_details`.`rack` SET `stockout_details`.`chaloutinv`=`stockin_details`.`inv_cha` ``